# PDFTK called via exec() fails silently

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm using [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to concatenate pdf files on the fly by making an exec() call like so:

```
exec("/path/to/pdftk /path/to/file1.pdf /path/to/file2.pdf cat output path/to/output.pdf", $execoutput);
```

This all works perfectly well in a linux environment, but when run locally on our development environments (a mix of Windows/Uniform Server and OSX/MAMP) this seems to silently fail. $execoutput is an empty array.

If the command that is sent to exec() is copy and pasted to the command line in either Windows or OSX it has the desired output and the concatenated file is generated. Each developer machine has pdftk installed and it can be demonstrated to be fully functional from the command line.

This currently has me stumped. I am at a loss to explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually figured out what was going on. Like a noob I had assumed every machine was running the latest version of pdftk. They weren't.

It would appear that the problem described above relates to a known bug which was fixed in version 1.43

**From http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/**

> "Clear the signal mask as workaround to environments that turn off signals before calling pdftk. This problem is known to cause pdftk to hang in some Python web setups as well as in PHP."

Guess which was the only setup to be running a version >= 1.43 ;-)

Updating each development environment to the latest version of pdftk (currently 1.44) has solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

This can also occur if pdftk does not have permission to the add the output to the desired folder. You can see this happening if you print out the $execoutput (with 'verbose' in the command) and see that the last entry will be 'Creating Output'. The next line should say that the output is being executed, but it will just end there. This got me for awhile (as it works if you run directly on the command line).